# Confused by this response to "Where have you been all these days?"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I asked my bae

> "Where have you been all these days?"

She replied

> "In your memory"

Memory refers to the thinking capacity of a person. It sounds same like in your mind, but she wants to say that she was thinking about me.
What word she could've said? Cause memory here in this sentence doesn't sound okay to my non native ears.

Comment: When she answers "in your memory", it means she assumes you have been thinking about her, not the other way around.

Comment: Okay but what if she meant she was thinking about me? How could she have said that

Comment: Please [edit] your question. A large part of the world [does not yet know what 'bae' means](http://www.esquire.com/lifestyle/news/a29423/where-did-bae-come-from/). It will help people answering your question.

Comment: I asked her. She meant she was thinking of me ...   I guess she was supposed to say in your memories(thoughts) . Because memory in its singular form doesnt work here. What say?

Comment: @JanDoggen They ought to look it up, don't you think?

Comment: @userr2684291 'Ought to' is irrelevant. If you want answers it helps to write clear questions. The number of people willing to answer questions is inversely proportional to the effort it takes to understand the question.

Comment: @JanDoggen In my defense I hadn't noticed the edit you made to your comment when I submitted mine. Nonetheless, it's just a tiny word, it's not as though this post has been filled with slang terms that render it impenetrable. Moreover, by my lights, the word isn't as arcane as you claim; that article was published three years ago, and I consider *bae* an aging slang term myself. (I'm not a native speaker of English, mind.)

Comment: Do you have a source for "where have you been all these days"?  While it doesn't sound entire *unnatural*, it does sound like it might be from a dialect.  I more often hear "where have you been **all this time**?"

Comment: @user236989 It doesn't matter if you use singular or plural. The issue is the phrase cannot be made to work at all with that word choice.  Basically the issue is the fact that this person has been thinking of you is not a literal answer to the question "where have you been"? And the phrase used means the opposite of its intent.   An acceptable metaphoric answer might be "[Lost] In thoughts/dreams of you".  "In your memory" refers to the thoughts _you_ had.  "In memory of <x>" is an idiom used for something entirely different, namely obituaries and in mourning of the deceased.

Comment: This is a thoughful, clever, and affectionate response. She phrased it very well (whether intentionally or not!)

Answer (score 4):

**Where have you been all these days?** is an expression that can be a direct question that is asking where the person has been, or what the person has been doing.

It can also be an indirect (implied question) that is stating that you have missed the person.  Some might also use the expression because they are annoyed that the person hasn't been around for a long time.

In each case the meaning is altered by the way the expression is asked using a different tone and inflection in your voice.

The answer (**in your memory**) doesn't make much sense to me and I have never heard that reply.

A more usual **reply** from your friend might be:

> I've been away on business, but you have been in **my thoughts.**

Another reply could be:

> I've been away on business, but I've been **thinking of you**.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the context here is that you were together, then you were apart, then you come back together and are asking what she was up to in the intervening time. If this is not the case (e.g. if you had never met before this instance), please edit the question to clarify

"In your memory" in this context makes sense. It implies that while you two were apart, you were reflecting on all the good times the two of you had together, your "memories" of her. You were reflecting on specific experiences of her in the past.

"In your thoughts" would also work, but would mean something slightly different. It would mean that you were thinking of her more generally during her absence. The implication is more that you were thinking about what she might be doing at that moment or about her as a person or your feelings about her.

EDIT: If she wants to say that she was thinking about you, not that you were thinking about her, she could say "In *my* thoughts." Likewise, if she was thinking about your good times together, she could say "in my memories." But "in my memories" would make the most sense if she was saying that your times together were very far in the past e.g. if you were  high school sweethearts meeting 10 years later.

Comment: It sounds like she wants to be smart and/or teases you: she *assumes* you were thinking of her.

Comment: oh! yeah, I missed from the questions, OP thinks "she wants to say that she was thinking about me." oops!

Comment: Yeah, but, see, if I asked you *Where have you been all these days?*, *In my thoughts* doesn't quite work as a reply meaning "You've been in my thoughts", does it now? Perhaps *(I've been) Thinking of you* works, however?

Comment: I stand by "in my thoughts". It's a little on the poetic side (especially for spoken English, but seems appropriate between lovers), but not unclear on incorrect.

Comment: Ah, alright, no worries then. (–1, that's not how I or anyone would interpret that; the "poetic" meaning is stretched too much for my liking.)